# How would I modify this xslt template to return local-name() notation instead?

Tags: xslt

I have this XSLT which does a great job of generating an xpath for each node in the xml document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="ez-xpath">
        <xsl:call-template name="genPath"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="ez-xpath-guid">
         <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="genPath">
    <xsl:param name="prevPath"/>
    <xsl:variable name="currPath" select="concat('/',name(),'[',
      count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])+1,']',$prevPath)"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="parent::*">
      <xsl:call-template name="genPath">
        <xsl:with-param name="prevPath" select="$currPath"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="not(parent::*)">
      <xsl:value-of select="$currPath"/>      
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I want to modify this template to return the xpath using local-name() instead. For example, let's say I have an xpath generated as something like

**`/Node1/Node2`**

but I want

**`/*[local-name()='Node1']/*[local-name()='Node2']`**

instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is a good idea, but if you want, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="ez-xpath">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                <xsl:text>/*[local-name()='</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
                <xsl:text>'][</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = local-name(current())]) + 1" />
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="ez-xpath-guid">
            <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for :-) Thanks!